# How to Get RTMP / HLS From Live Stream Link?

Tags: rtmp, http-live-streaming

anyone knows is that a fastest way to get rtmp/hls/m3u8 from stream link ?

example stream : 
- http://www.tvonlineku.com/2013/12/trans-7-streaming.html
- http://www.tvstreamingku.com/2014/03/streaming-trans-tv.html

usually i use IDM (Internet Download Manager) application, it will appear on the right top side of the stream when playing. but in this stream i try to use IDM but it wont appear, anyone know another way to get the rtmp link?

thank you

regards - john...

Comment: What I usually do is to open the page source and search for `rtmp` or `m3u8`. Alternatively you can look at the network requests and find the one for the stream. This doesn't work with `rtmp` because `rtmp` usually doesn't show in the `network` tab of a javascript debugger.

Comment: @syetlin mladenov thanks very much !

Comment: I just posted my comment as an answer. @raye-joe, the stackoverflow way of saying "thank you" is to accept my answer. Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is to open the page source code and search for `rtmp` or `m3u8`. Alternatively you can look at the network requests and find the one for the stream. This doesn't work with `rtmp` because it uses `udp` and usually doesn't show in the `network` tab of a javascript debugger.